# I am having problems with my NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, ios4, nspredicate

I'm trying the following comparison but it does not work.

What is the appropriate syntax to use both the or/and operator within the same context?

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((day || day2 ==%@) && CourseTitle==%@)",day,courseSelected];
rows = [[courseArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]retain];
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(((day == %@) OR (day2 == %@)) && CourseTitle==%@)",day, day, courseSelected];
rows = [[courseArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]retain];
```